# How to better reduce classes dependencies so it is easier to Unit-Test them

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, oop, dependencies

I am developing a Genetic Algorithm framework and initially decided on the following `IIndividual` definition:

```
public interface IIndividual : ICloneable
{
    int NumberOfGenes { get; }
    double Fitness { get; }
    IGene GetGeneAt(int index);
    void AddGene(IGene gene);
    void SetGeneAt(int index, IGene gene);
    void Mutate();
    IIndividual CrossOverWith(IIndividual individual);
    void CalculateFitness();
    string ToString();
}
```

It looked alright, but as soon as I developed other classes that used `IIndividual`, I came to the conclusion that making Unit-Tests for those classes would be kind of painful. To understand why, I'll show you the dependency graph of `IIndividual`:

[image]

So, when using `IIndividual`, I end up to also having to create/manage instances of `IGene` and `IInterval`.
I can easily solve the issue, redefining my `IIndividual` interface to the following:

```
public interface IIndividual : ICloneable
{
    int NumberOfGenes { get; }
    void AddGene(double value, double minValue, double maxValue);
    void SetGeneAt(int index, double value);
    double GetGeneMinimumValue(int index);
    double GetGeneMaximumValue(int index);
    double Fitness { get; }
    double GetGeneAt(int index);
    void Mutate();
    IIndividual CrossOverWith(IIndividual individual);
    void CalculateFitness();
    string ToString();
}
```

with the following dependency graph:

[image]

This will be pretty easy to test, at the expense of some performance degradation (I'm at this moment not that worried about that) and having `IIndividual` heavier (more methods). There is also a big problem for the clients of IIndividual, as if they want to add a Gene, they'll have to add all the little parameters of Gene "manually" in `AddGene(value, minimumValue, maximumValue)`, instead of `AddGene(gene)`!

### My question is:

What design do you prefer and why? Also, what is the criteria to know where to stop?

I could do just the same thing I did to `IIndividual` to `IGene`, so anyone that uses `IGene` doesn't have to know about `Interval`.
I have a class `Population` that will serve as a collection of `IIndividuals`. What stops me from doing the same I did to `IIndividual` to `Population`? There must be some kind of boundary, some kind of criteria to understand in which cases is best to just let it be (have some dependencies) and in which cases it is best to hide them (like in the second `IIndividual` implementation).

Also, when implementing a framework that's supposed to be used by other people, I feel like the second design is less pretty (and is maybe harder for others to understand).

Thanks!

Comment: statements like this worry me: "This will be pretty easy to test, at the expense of some performance degradation"

Comment: Why? ............... Actually, now that I think of it, maybe the performance will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@andersoj has you on the right track regard Feather's book, but here's some deeper analysis:

Eric Evans *Domain Driven Design* addresses the type of boundary you're pondering. The [free InfoQ summarization](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) is a good place to start as the Evans is too verbose in my humble opinion. What Evans describes as Aggregate Roots are the type of boundary I think you need to consider

Individual looks like an aggregate root, implying Genes and Intervals only exist for, and can only be created by, the Individual class. Assuming then these classes don't need to be used by clients, your refactoring of the Individual class to effectively hide, or remove, the other two makes sense.

On the other hand, if clients do need access to Gene and Interval independently of the individual I suggest considering making them immutable so the state of the Individual cannot be altered implicitly.

In either case, start with characterization tests. That is tests that capture what the code is doing **now**. Then refactor from there.

Answer (score 1):

(I apologize for not directly answering your question, but I can't help but point you this way...) 
I can't suggest the book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) (author Michael Feathers) highly enough.  It's an outstanding treatment of the challenges of getting code under (unit, functional) test.

Comment: That book is in my To-Read list for ages. I'll try to give it a read some day :(